# Connecting to MSSQL with Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

So I got project. It's complete and it should work, now I'm trying to run it.
It's using PHP 5.6 and Codeigniter, DB is MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS. I'm running project on XAMPP
Here's my db config:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
$db['default']['port'] = '1433';
$db['default']['username'] = 'user';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password1234';
$db['default']['database'] = 'DataBase004';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = strncasecmp(PHP_OS, 'WIN', 3) == 0 ? 'sqlsrv' : 'mssql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

It looks correct, but in logs I always get errors like:

```
ERROR - 2016-08-26 00:55:22 --> Unable to connect to the database
ERROR - 2016-08-26 00:55:22 --> Unable to connect to the database
ERROR - 2016-08-26 00:55:22 --> Severity: Warning  --> sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given C:\xampp\htdocs\prompt-web\src\resources\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\sqlsrv_driver.php 152
ERROR - 2016-08-26 00:55:22 --> Severity: Warning  --> sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given C:\xampp\htdocs\prompt-web\src\resources\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\sqlsrv_driver.php 152
ERROR - 2016-08-26 00:55:22 --> Unable to connect to the database
ERROR - 2016-08-26 00:55:22 --> Severity: Warning  --> sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given C:\xampp\htdocs\prompt-web\src\resources\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\sqlsrv_driver.php 152
ERROR - 2016-08-26 00:55:22 --> Severity: Warning  --> sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given C:\xampp\htdocs\prompt-web\src\resources\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\sqlsrv_driver.php 152
```

And here's page from server:
[image]
In php/ext I got drivers:
`php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` and `php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll`
I added it to php.ini:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

Should I do anythink else?
I tried to solve it in many different ways.

Comment: Wait a minute, I did this and will answer in a while.Wait what version of codeigniter is this?

Answer (score 1):

The host name is wrong. Oopen your mssql and see the login. The server name should be the hostname. sometimes it's named as.

```
YOURPC\SQLEXPRESS
```

Put that in the hostname and it should work. Also, did you restart xampp?

Goodluck

[image: This is my configuration]

**EDIT**

The one inside the blue circle should be your hostname.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I changed host name to `MyPC\SQLEXPRESS`, then I restarted XAMPP, but it's still same errors. Maybe there somethink else which I should do?

Comment: Is it really MyPC\SQLEXPRESS? I'll update my answer and from there you might see what you're missing.

Comment: Yes I'm 100% sure, but it's still the same

Comment: What version of codeigniter are you using? Did you change the db driver to what's written on mine? Have you autoloaded the database driver in autoload of codeigniter?

Comment: And If i helped you, can you also help me too by giving me an upvote and/or a checkmark :)

Comment: Mango: How to autload the DB driver? Any links?

Comment: Go to your codeigniter folder -> application -> config -> autoload.php

then find $autoload['libraries'] = array();

add in the array database to make

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');

Comment: OK so I'm using version: '2.1.4', I found autoload and it's actually correct: `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','user', 'common/paged_request', 'common/paged_result');`, and my driver is set to: `$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';` but it still not work :/

Comment: Hmmm. you had a fatal error. If I'm right, you already have a controller and a model. Can we take a look at that too? Might help me in debugging your work :D

Comment: You mean system/core/Controller.php and system/core/Model.php ? I could post it, but I think problem is with connection it can't even establish it

Comment: You had a fatal error on num rows, meaning you're already working on something. But is there any chance you could download the latest codeigniter? My solution would work there, on an old codeigniter I'm not sure if my solutions heps too much.. What's the reason for using 2.1.4?

Comment: I can't change version it's not my project, owner is actually on vacation so I can't ask him. I added Model.php and Cotroller.php as edit in my question (first post)

Comment: Oh okay, anyway you can delete that,what i need is from the applications->controllers folder and applications->models folder. :)

Comment: Ok, but there is a lot of models and controllers there, so problably I will have problem with posting this stuff. But maybe you could give me more suggestions, for example how to deug it? Maybe display something (echo())? I just want to somehow figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-download the SQLSRV driver.
download the SQLSRV30.EXE.

I used the SQLSRV32.EXE but occurs error just like yours.
Hope this helps :)